Is there a way to run a Postman collection directly from C# code?
I need to automate some APIs using RestSharp. I have a Postman collection with all the APIs. I was wondering if there is a library available out there that reads a Postman collection and executes API requests one by one.
Meanwhile, I am writing custom C# code to read the Postman collection and hit the APIs. I have been partially successful so far but I anticipate some issues later on. So hoping there is a ready solution out there.

I had the same problem where I couldn't find a simple program to run postman collections with the features I wanted.
I created and using my own https://github.com/AlbertoDino/jayman
Feel free to have a look
